# Android Studio lint_baseline.xml does not exclude many issues that it should

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, android-lint

I have this in my build.gradle:

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    absolutePaths false
    lintConfig file('lint.xml')
    baseline file('lint-baseline.xml')
  }
}
```

And I have run `Analyze > Inspect Code` previously to establish this baseline. I've also confirmed that this file does in fact exist, and is populated with issues to ignore.

However I still have many warnings showing up when I run `Analyze > Inspect Code`.  It seems that the issues that are not excluded based on the baseline are those not listed by `lint --list`/the ones listed [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks).

They include 'Unused declaration', 'Field can be local', etc.

Is there any way to filter these out as well? Why does the code inspection check for warnings/errors that lint does not list as issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android Studio inspections:

> Lint can be configured with a "baseline"; a set of current issues found in a codebase, which future runs of lint will silently ignore. Only new issues not found in the baseline are reported.
>
> Note that while opening files in the IDE, baseline issues are not filtered out; the purpose of baselines is to allow you to get started using lint and break the build on all newly introduced errors, without having to go back and fix the entire codebase up front. However, when you open up existing files you still want to be aware of and fix issues as you come across them.
>
> This issue type is used to emit two types of informational messages in reports: first, whether any issues were filtered out so you don't have a false sense of security if you forgot that you've checked in a baseline file, and second, whether any issues in the baseline file appear to have been fixed such that you can stop filtering them out and get warned if the issues are re-introduced.

I was just wondering the same thing. Maybe that will help explain things.

The baseline feature is intended to hide linting errors in the console and make it so that **new warnings/errors** will break the build. Unfortunately this doesn't suppress Android Studio inspections.

[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're talking about how the lint baseline will not suppress the issues when I view a file in the IDE, yes? 

If that's the case, this isn't exactly what I'm talking about. Rather, I'm seeing the actual inspection return with lint issues, when running the code inspection _immediately after_ setting the baseline, with no code changes. To me, this seems to defeat the whole purpose of setting a baseline

Comment: Okay so yes and no. The baseline ONLY affects the CLI tool/Gradle task. Run the "lint" task in your module. If it is set up correctly, it will use the baseline and not report an error/warning with the exception of simply letting you know that it is using a baseline. When I run it via the Gradle task, it works as expected but only for the CLI tool, not for `Analyze > Inspect Code`. 

In summary, the baseline cannot affect anything in the IDE: inline inspections for an open file nor the `Analyze > Inspect Code` window. It can suppress warnings/errors when running from the CLI tool/Gradle only

Answer (score 3):

I used these lines to fix

```
   lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    absolutePaths false
    lintConfig file('lint.xml')
}
```